# AngularJS Select with ng-options binding to object not property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am trying to bind a select list to ng-model state abbreviation value.. for instance "AK" for Alaska.  The initial selection doesn't work apparently because the ng-model is set to a string instead of an object.  I've looked all over and there are all other people that have this issue but I haven't found a solution that works.

my controller has the following code

```
  $scope.states =
            [
            {
                "name": "Alabama",
                "abbreviation": "AL"
            },
            {
                "name": "Alaska",
                "abbreviation": "AK"
            },
            {
                "name": "Arizona",
                "abbreviation": "AZ"
            }];

  //I want the model to be the abbreviation string
  $scope.state = "AK";
```

Here is the markup

```
<select class="form-control m-b" data-placeholder="Select Location" 
required=""  ng-model="state" 
ng-options="state as state.name for state in states track by state.abbreviation">
                            </select>

    <p>Selected State {{state}}!</p>
```

Here is a plnkr that shows shat I'm talking about

https://plnkr.co/edit/IzDY4GrOxJSaMV2MMP30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

> `$scope.state.abbreviation`

to get the abrevation of the state object that's selected.

[plkr solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/GR6UIc6LzY3o2HjX8PIw)

OR

you could change the ng-options to

> `ng-options="state.abbreviation as state.name for state in states track by state.abbreviation"`

Comment: Thanks, that second option is what I was looking for, the model is now the abbreviation.  Thank You!  I still have a problem where the initial selection isn't set to "Alaska".  I created this plnkr...  https://plnkr.co/edit/OC2DVIlOmpHw75I9ERI8

Comment: The problem with doing something like that is that the ng-model needs to be set to an object in the list of ng-options to set it from the controller. Is there a reason you can't do something like [this plkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pTndZbXoDSfILiU80IQk)?

Comment: No, there isn't a reason that I can't do it.  I was just hoping to only work with the abbreviations and not have to lookup the object from the abbreviation.  I was hoping that with ng-model being set properly that it could be bound to the abbreviation initially.